# How to get docker image from Harbor registry in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, rancher, harbor

Installed Harbor on one host(192.168.33.10).

Installed Kubernetes cluster on other hosts.

Pushed docker images to Harbor host from client successfully. On Kubernets master host, I can also pull that image from Harbor host successfully:

```
$ docker pull 192.168.33.10/hello-world/hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from hello-world/hello-world
3d19aeb159d4: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:d9f41d096c0e1881e7a24756db9b7315d91c8d4bf1537f6eb10c36edeedde59f
Status: Downloaded newer image for 192.168.33.10/hello-world/hello-world:latest
```

But I created a Kubernetes deployment yaml file as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1                                                                                                                                                                          
kind: Deployment                                                                                                                                                                                        
metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  name: hello-world                                                                                                                                                                                     
spec:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  template:                                                                                                                                                                                             
    metadata:                                                                                                                                                                                           
      labels:                                                                                                                                                                                           
        app: hello-world                                                                                                                                                                                
    spec:                                                                                                                                                                                               
      containers:                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - image: 192.168.33.10/hello-world/hello-world                                                                                                                                                    
        name: hello-world                                                                                                                                                                               
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Then run `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

From Kubernetes dashboard it showed:

```
Failed to pull image "192.168.33.10/hello-world/hello-world": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://192.168.33.10/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.33.10:443: getsockopt: connection refused"}
Error syncing pod
```

[image]

I already set `insecure-registries` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{ "insecure-registries":["192.168.33.10"] }
```

How can get that from Kubernetes?

---

## Edit

I am using Kubernetes on Rancher server cluster. Even I set Harbor server's IP, username and password, it can't access, too:

[image]

Comment: What are you using for Kubernetes? Is it minikube? If it is not, what is the OS on worker nodes?

Comment: @Nickolay I edited the question above and added a picture. I am using Rancher server to setup K8S cluster now. The OS are all CentOS 7.

Comment: http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/registries/#adding-registries The reason was didn't set `insecure-registry` to Rancher agent hosts.

Comment: I am trying with minikube some of the image i am able to deploy but some images are failing with error synch error